# Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate with -CertificateString throws error

Tags: powershell, azure-keyvault, pfx, tobase64string

I'm trying to import a self signed PFX certificate (with private key) in Azure Key Vault with the `Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate` command using the `-CertificateString` parameter.

But when I run this command I get the following error message:

> Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate : The specified PKCS#12 X.509 certificate
> content can not be read. Please check if certificate is in valid
> PKCS#12 format. Status: 400 (Bad Request)

I can import the very same PFX certificate manually in Key Vault, without any problems. But I need to do this using `-CertificateString` for a deployment script.

So I converted my PFX certificate into a Base64 string using PowerShell:

```
$fileContentBytes = get-content ".\myCert.pfx" -Encoding Byte
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fileContentBytes) | Out-File ".\pfx-base64.txt"
```

Multiple sites showed that this is the way to convert a PFX cert to a Base64 string. One of them is this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/258583/import-certificate-api-for-azure-key-vault.html

I then use that string in PowerShell like so:

```
$Secure_String_Pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "MySecretPassword" -AsPlainText -Force;
Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName "MyKeyVault" -Name "cert-signing" -CertificateString "MIIJagIBAzCCCSYGCS.....9oV21QwICB9A=" -Password $Secure_String_Pwd;
```

I don't understand why its throwing an error. The certificate seems to be fine when I upload it manually. Why doesn't it work in a Base64 form?

Comment: please check this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60242993/unable-to-import-certificate-using-api-in-powershell)

Comment: You are sending a request and the content type has to match the data in the body of the request.  If you are sending a base64 string (sent in body of request), then the content type as to be a base 64 type.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to import certificate in my environment.***

Here when trying to import certificate , it has to be imported with password.
***`For that the certificate while creating must be set with password so that while importing .pfx certificate private key is secured with password.`***

In cloud shell while setting up self signed certificate , set with password.

[image]

Or check below code from [azure - Unable to "Import Certificate" using API in PowerShell - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60242993/unable-to-import-certificate-using-api-in-powershell?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Check if the password  is sent in correct format and try sending instead converting to securestring.

Ex:

```
$kvname = "newkaazurekeyvault"
$certname = "kaselfsignedcertific"
$tenantId ="xxxxxxxxx"
$subId="bxxxxxxx"
Connect-AzAccount -Subscription $subscriptionId -Tenant $tenantId

$resource="xxxxx"
$context= Get-AzContext
$token = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account,
 $context.Environment, 
 $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), 
 $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, $resource).AccessToken

$pfxcontent = Get-Content ‘C:\Users\vxxx\kaazurekeyvault-kaselfsixxx-2xxx.pfx' -Encoding Byte
$base64pfxcontent = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($pfxcontent)

$json_new = @{
  value= $base64Stringpfxcontent
  pwd= "Pxxx234"
  policy= @{
    secret_props= @{
      contentType= "application/x-pkcs12"
    }
  }
}

$json = $json_new | ConvertTo-Json

$header = @{Authorization = "Bearer " + $token }
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "https://$kvname.vault.azure.net/certificates/$certname/import?api-version=7.0" -Body $json -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json"
```

[image]

***So try to Export the certificate in PFX with password***

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password!" -AsPlainText -Force

Export-PfxCertificate -Cert "cert:\CurrentUser\My\$($cert.Thumbprint)" -FilePath C:\temp\cert2.pfx -Password $password
```

***Then try to import that pfx certificate using the password.***

```
 Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName tempvault -Name certifcte -FilePath C:\temp\cert.pfx -Password $password
```

Then the certificate is imported successfully.

[image]